# PLSQL WHERE date_time is in a range of dates

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle9i

I have two date strings, in the format MM/DD/YYYY and would like to query an Oracle database for any records between those two dates.  How do I do this succinctly and simply?

Comment: This is not specific to oracle9i.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [TO_DATE function](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php):

```
WHERE date_column BETWEEN TO_DATE(start, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
                      AND TO_DATE(end, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN to_date('01/05/2010','mm/dd/yyyy') AND to_date('10/01/2010','mm/dd/yyyy') ORDER BY date ASC
```

Comment: Answered your own question inside of two minutes, eh?

Comment: Yeah, usually I use SO as a parallel research tool.  If I need to know something, I'll set the community on it on SO and search for the answer myself at the same time.

Comment: wow - really?  Remind me not to spend time on your questions until I give you some time to try a search engine first.

Comment: Also I think this one in particular I didn't find a good source for elsewhere, so I put it here for others to find.